# Why an ID passed via Class' constructor is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, dataset

In my code, I want to pass a unique ID to the li by using a class.
However, whenever I refresh the page, the "data-id" attribute is always changing. So the ID becomes different every time the page is reloaded.

Is there a way to make it static but not setting a preset ID?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li id="item">ID check</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    class IdChecker {
        constructor() {
            this.id = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
        }
    }
    let item = document.getElementById('item');
    item.setAttribute('data-id', String(new IdChecker().id))
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code inside the script tag is run everytime you refresh the page. If you would like to have persistent id, consider saving it in local storage

Comment: When the page reloads, the old content is obliterated and replaced by the new content, and your code runs again. If you want a unique automatic id, you have to do that on the server. *edit* yes or local storage, though it's not clear what the point is anyway.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. You know why the ID is always changing, right? You’re calling `Math.random`, so every time you use the constructor, you get a new random number. How exactly is a random but static ID going to look like? Intuitively, you’re setting a unique ID to the “same” `<li>` element, but how exactly do you determine “sameness” in terms of JS? Also, what do you need this ID for and why does it need to remain the same accross multiple page loads?

Comment: ... in addition the OP might consider using the `dataset` property of an element node ... instead of ... `item.setAttribute('data-id', /* ... */)` ... do ... `item.dataset.id = /* ... */`.